# feynmp - ! Missing $ inserted

Tags: feynmf

I'm trying to execute the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}

\begin{document}
\unitlength = 1mm
% determine the unit for the size of diagram.

\begin{fmffile}{fmfile}{simple_tree}
\begin{fmfgraph}{50,35}
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,o6,o7,o8,o9,o10,o11}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
\fmf{gluon}{v1,v2}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v2,v3}
\fmf{fermion}{v3,v4,v5,o3}
\fmf{fermion}{v5,v6}
\fmf{fermion}{o4,o5}
\end{fmffile} 
\end{document}
```

However, I get an error that begins with

```
! Missing $ inserted
```

May I ask where I am going wrong here?

**Edit**: I've changed the code as follows, with the `feynmp-auto` and graph corrections:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\unitlength = 40mm
% determine the unit for the size of diagram.

\begin{fmffile}{simple_tree}
\begin{fmfgraph}(50,35)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2,o3,o4,o5}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
\fmf{gluon}{v1,v2}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v2,v3}
\fmf{fermion}{v3,v4,v5,o3}
\fmf{gluon}{v5,v6}
\fmf{fermion}{o4,v6,o5}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Now however I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `feynmp-auto.sty' not found.
```

from Texmaker. I used command line and get the same thing.

Comment: The `$`-complaint references the use of `_` in `simple_tree`. However, your minimal document won't compile for other reasons as well. For example, the environment `fmfgraph` is never closed.

Comment: You have several errors: `\begin{fmffile}{simple_tree}` (an argument too many); `\begin{fmfgraph}(50,35)` (parentheses rather than braces); an `\end{fmfgraph}` is also missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the `fmffile` environment is

```
\begin{fmffile}{<filename>}
```

so with your code the file name is `fmfile` and LaTeX doesn't know what to do with `{simple_tree}` and so tries to typeset it.

The file name is that of the output Metapost file; if you want to call it `simple_tree`, say

```
\begin{fmffile}{simple_tree}
```

There's an error also in the following line, which should be

```
\begin{fmfgraph}(50,35)
```

with parentheses rather than braces.

Finally, `\end{fmfgraph}` is missing. Correct code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
% determine the unit for the size of diagram.

\begin{fmffile}{simple_tree}
\begin{fmfgraph}(50,35)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,o6,o7,o8,o9,o10,o11}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
\fmf{gluon}{v1,v2}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v2,v3}
\fmf{fermion}{v3,v4,v5,o3}
\fmf{fermion}{v5,v6}
\fmf{fermion}{o4,o5}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile} 
\end{document}
```

### Note

Compiling this with Metapost gives errors:

```
feynmf: warning: dangling vertex `v6' colliding with `v5'.
feynmf: Have you seen the warning messages above?
        They are usually caused by misspelling a vertex'
        name and can trigger errors further below!
        Fix the typos and run LaTeX and Metafont again.
```

Fix the code before trying.

### Suggestion

If you have an up-to-date TeX distribution you can change

```
\usepackage{feynmp}
```

into

```
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
```

that will take care of the Metapost run (two LaTeX runs are necessary anyway if the code in the `fmffile` environment is changed).

Comment: I entered the code, but it compiles and gives a completely white pdf document- is there something wrong with the line colour?

Comment: You have to run Metapost over the produced `simple_tree.mp` file. If you have an updated TeX distribution, you can try changing `\usepackage{feynmp}` with `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}`, which will take care of this auxiliary step (two LaTeX runs are needed). But there are errors in the `fmgraph` code that you should correct beforehand.